# Transforming the exponential function of a sum into the sum of functions

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Is there a way to transform the function
$$\exp(A+B+C),$$
where $\exp(\cdot)$ is the exponential function, into a sum
$$f(A)+f(B)+f(C)?$$

Comment: what exactly is exp?

Comment: Question edited

Comment: Well this might by a ditzy answer, but can't you just take the logarithm? Then you are left with $A + B + C$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly you would like to know if there is a suitable function  $f$ such that  $e^{a+b+c}=f(a)+f(b)+f(c)$ for all values of $a,b,c$.

Notice such a function would satisfy $f(0)+f(0)+f(0)=e^0=1$. So $f(0)=\frac{1}{3}$.

From here we can determine the function uniquely, since we must have $e^x=f(x)+f(0)+f(0)=f(x)+\frac{2}{3}$.

So the function $f$ needs to be $f(x)=e^x-\frac{2}{3}$

We can see easily this doesn't work since if it did we would have $e^3=f(1)+f(1)+f(1)=3(e-\frac{1}{3})=3e-1$ which clearly is not true.

---

Shorter solution for generalized version which proves there are no three functions $f,g,h$ so that $f(a)+g(b)+h(c)=e^x: $

Note $f(x)=e^x-g(0)-h(0)$. We can do the same to the rest and get all the functions are $e^x$ minus a constant.This isn't possible since then $f(x)+g(x)+h(x)=3e^x-c$ which is a lot smaller than $e^{3x}$ for large values of $x$.

Comment: To take it further, I wondered if a small escapade is valid or at least interesting:

The equation ee^3 - 3 ee + 1 = 0 has three approx. real roots, the root ee should serve as a new substitute base in place of e, the Naperian log base.Roots are 

$ (.347729, 1.532088,-1.879385) = ( \alpha,\beta,\gamma) $.

Taking any of them as a new base,

$ f(x)= ee^x -2/3 $ is the required function, and so is not 

 $ \alpha^{(a+b+c)} = f(a) + f(b) + f(c) $ for all $ (a,b,c) $ ? 

I find this approximation not way too off the mark. Please comment.

Comment: With such approximate satisfaction of the relation, I get some sense of what OP Cris is conveying, extending inter dependent relations that you gave.. Please comment.

Comment: Ok, I need some time to think, I'll answer later

Comment: That's super interesting, could you idea be rearranged to  answer this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061237/approximating-a-function-by-a-sum-of-functions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JorgeFernández could you give more details abour your idea using three different functions f,g,h?

Answer (score 1):

No. It is multiplicative, not additive.
$$
\exp(A + B + C) = 
\exp(A) \exp(B) \exp(C)
$$

Counter example:
$$
\exp(x+x+x) = f(x) + f(x) + f(x) \iff
f(x) = 1/3 \exp(3x) \\
e = \exp(1 + 0 + 0) =^! 1/3 \exp(3) + 2/3 \exp(0) > 7
$$

Comment: what do you mean bot additive?

Comment: Spell correction for the wrong language did this, sorry.

Comment: This doesn't prove that $\exp(A+B+C)$ can't possibly be written as $f(A)+f(B)+f(C)$.

Comment: Well I know the rules of exponential functions. I was wondering if there are some other functions (e.g. logarithm functions) that allow to write the product of exponential functions as a sum

Comment: You can log that statement, but then it is $\ln \circ \exp$ with that property and not $\exp$.