# Approximating a function by a sum of functions

Tags: functions

I have a function 
$$
f(A,B,C):=\frac{\gamma-\delta \exp(\beta A+\omega B+C)}{1+\exp(\beta A+\omega B+C)}
$$
where $\gamma, \delta, \beta, \omega$ are parameters.

Do you know if there is a way to **approximate** this function as
$$
g(A,B, D):=Z(A;\tilde{\gamma})+v(B;\tilde{\omega})+m(D; \tilde{\xi})
$$
where $Z(\cdot;\tilde{\gamma})$ is any function of $A$, $m(\cdot; \tilde{\xi})$ is any function of $D$ (where $D$ can be a transformation of $C$), $v(\cdot;\tilde{\omega})$ is a monotone function of $B$ and $\tilde{\gamma}, \tilde{\omega}, \tilde{\xi}$ are parameters?

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Preface

This question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061174/transforming-the-exponential-function-of-a-sum-into-the-sum-of-functions/1061177#1061177).

#### First shot

This is the linear approximation around $0 = (0,0,0)^t$:
\begin{align}
f(A,B,C)
&=
f(0,0,0) + \left. \mbox{grad } f \right|_{0} \cdot (A,B,C)^t + O(h^2) 
&=
f(0,0,0) 
+ \\ 
& \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial A} f(A,B,C)\right|_0 \, A
+ \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial B} f(A,B,C)\right|_0 \, B
+ \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial C} f(A,B,C)\right|_0 \, C
+ O(h^2)
\\
&= 
\frac{\gamma-\delta}{2} +
\frac{-\delta\beta\exp(0)(1+\exp(0))
-(\gamma-\delta\exp(0))\beta\exp(0)}{(1+\exp(0))^2}A + \cdots \\
&=
\underbrace{
\frac{\gamma-\delta}{2}
-\frac{(\gamma+\delta)\beta}{4}A 
-\frac{(\gamma+\delta)\omega}{4}B
-\frac{\gamma+\delta}{4}C
}_{L_0(A,B,C)}
+ O(h^2)
\end{align}

#### Overview

Here is a simplified version (1d, parameters set to $1$) of your function:
[image: 1d params 1]!
Outside $[-5,5]$ it is mostly constant, around $0$ it is mostly linear.

Next step would be to add linear approximations around $\pm 2$, which would improve the fitting.

Going to 2d gives this:

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{1-\exp(x+y)}{1+\exp(x+y)}
$$

[image: 2d case]

The qualitative behaviour is the same: constant value planes fit for large arguments, around the origin a plane fits good as well.
Setting the parameters different from $1$ will only adjust levels and angles.

The gradient is $(-1/4, -1/4)^t$.

For 3d it is harder to visualise ([link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/59994/how-to-visualize-a-3d-scalar-function)).

#### Outer space

The 3d case should resemble the 1d and 2d cases in that the function is more or less constant for large argument values.
\begin{align}
\lim_{(A,B,C)^t \to \infty (1,1,1)^t} f(A,B,C) 
&=
\lim_{r \to \infty} f(r,r,r) \\
&=
\lim_{r \to \infty}
\frac{\gamma - \delta \exp(\beta r + \omega r + r)}{1 + \exp(\beta r + \omega r + r)} \\
&=
\lim_{r \to \infty}
\frac{\gamma - \delta \exp((\beta + \omega + 1)r)}{1 + \exp((\beta + \omega + 1)r)} \\
&= 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cr}
-\delta & \mbox{ for } \beta + \omega + 1 > 0 \\
\frac{\gamma - \delta}{2} & \mbox{ for } \beta + \omega + 1 = 0 \\
\gamma & \mbox{ for } \beta + \omega + 1 < 0
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\lim_{(A,B,C)^t \to -\infty (1,1,1)^t} f(A,B,C) 
&=
\lim_{r \to -\infty} f(r,r,r) \\
&=
\lim_{r \to -\infty}
\frac{\gamma - \delta \exp((\beta + \omega + 1)r)}{1 + \exp((\beta + \omega + 1)r)} \\
&= 
\left\{
\begin{array}{cr}
\gamma & \mbox{ for } \beta + \omega + 1 > 0 \\
\frac{\gamma - \delta}{2} & \mbox{ for } \beta + \omega + 1 = 0 \\
-\delta & \mbox{ for } \beta + \omega + 1 < 0
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}

#### Stitching it together

The idea is this:  The gradient 
$$
\left(
-\frac{(\gamma+\delta)\beta}{4},
-\frac{(\gamma+\delta)\omega}{4},
-\frac{\gamma+\delta}{4}
\right)^t
$$
is a normal vector to the approximation plane around $(0,0,0)^t$. That plane separates $\mathbb{R}^3$ into two half-spaces.

[image: 2d / level curves]

There should be two additional planes parallel to the middle plane, where $f$ gets nearly constant, like in the 2d case the $0.99$ level curves. 
So that would cut $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $3$ parts, two outer spaces where one uses the proper constant there as an approximation and the inner space where one uses $L_{0}(A,B,C)$ as approximation.

Comment: That approximation of $f$ that I suggest is piecewise linear and can be written as your $g$. I try to spell it out.

Comment: The outer space is where the function becomes constant right? And do you have also some more details on the structure of O(h^2)?  I'm asking this, because, if I use the approximation you provide, D=-(gamma+delta)/4*C+O(h^2), but I'm wondering whether O(h^2) is a function of A,B as well.

Comment: Have a look here at the case in several dimensions: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions). The Taylor theorem gives a polynomial in $A$, $B$ and $C$. It makes no sense to invest much work here without knowing the application.